# Easy way to install RTools

Tags: r, rstudio, rtools

Is there a way to make R(v3.6.0 and higher) and Rstudio recognize RTools (v4.2) in Windows 11? Using the Install Wizard does not work, and all info on the subject is contradictory (some answers tell you to put RTools on the PATH, but others say that is not recomended)

Comment: Using the install wizard *should* work. That’s the “easy way”: it should work out of the box.

Comment: One reason for contradictions in the docs is that Rtools has changed over time.  I don't know if v4.2 (the newest version) will work with R 3.6.0 (quite an old version), but it isn't tested there.  See https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ for the intended matches.

Comment: Konrad Rudolph: It does not :/ i even tried a clean install of everything (R, Rstudio and Rtools), it is still not recognized

Comment: I have tried with R 3.6.0, 4.1.0 and 4.2.1 (current version). None have worked so far

Comment: What exactly hasn't "worked"? What are you testing with? You should only use the version of RTools for the corresponding version of R. They need to be in sync. The same version of RTools will not work with both R 3.* and R 4.*.

Comment: It never get recognize (I always get the "WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:" message). I am testing with install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source"). I have used all combinations of R 4.1.0 and 4.2.1 to try to use Rtools 40 or 42. I uninstall everything every time, re-download it and try again. It hasn´t work so far